# SOAP webservice call returning null but Postman it give result

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsse

Calling a SOAP webservice as below. Security used by the client is Wsse security

```
DD.WritePortTypeClient client = new DD.WritePortTypeClient();
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                                                new SecurityHeader("Username", "Password"));

ResponseType result_obj = new ResponseType();

result_obj =   client.createPolicies(inputobj);
client.Close();
}

The wsse security is doing dynamically using SecurityHeader()

The code is running without any error but the result_obj is coming as null.
What am i missing here.
```

> Edit1

Checked the same as in Comment using Fiddler4. The response is coming there. But at program the object is coming as null.

Comment: Use a tool that shows the actual SOAP requests that you code uses, (something like Fiddler4) and compare that with postman.   You are probably missing some headers.

Comment: @Neil installed Fiddler4 and checked the same response is coming successfully at fiddler4..but application giving null

Comment: OK, so that means the deserialsation is incorrect.

Comment: @Neil yes, contacted the web sevice provider..they saying the wsdl is correct..